# How to convert while loop into foreach in this code?

Tags: php, php-5.3

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Video display</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    $directory="video/";
    if(is_dir($directory))
    {
        if($openfile=(opendir($directory)))
        {
            while(($video=readdir($openfile))!==false)
            {
                if($video!="." && $video!="..")
                {
                ?>
                    <video controls autoplay>
                        <source src="video/<?php echo $video;?>"/>
                    </video>
                <?php
                    echo $video;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($openfile);
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is working perfectly but i want displaying videos in **foreach loop** so How to convert while loop into **foreach loop** in this code?

Comment: No, the while() loop is perfect here. If you really need foreach, read about the DirectoryIterator.

Comment: You can also read all first and then iterate it with foreach, but I don't get why you need foreach so much. While is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`glob`**](https://www.php.net/glob)

```
<?php

foreach( glob("videos/*") as $strFileName) {
    echo "<video controls autoplay>
            <source src=\"video/". $strFileName ."\"/>
          </video>";
}
```

Comment: thank you so much  I what to know what are the standard video format run in html5 because administrator will upload any type of video, now i am going to restrict with .mp4,.webm,ogg I don't know administrator  will upload any format type video, what is the bottom line means is there is any specific device to have mp4 format

Comment: You're welcome. According to [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-cross-browser-video-playback-in-html5/), [these are the formats](http://i.imgur.com/yoJP0wE.png) in a table for browser compatibility. This would suggest it's either "MP4", "OGV", "WEBM". (I've not done much with HTML5 videos, so I may be wrong/not entirely correct)

Comment: thanks lot I have read the link Miro Video Converter,now my question is how do i embed Miro Video Converter, in admin part so that convert video to these format mp4 ogv webm.ask some one and help me dude...we both learn

Comment: @Rangarajakrishnan I would open another question :)